# Recreating a ContourPlot3D using points

Tags: plotting, graphics

Let's define a three-dimensional surface

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Φcl = (-G*Mcl)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + a^2];
Φeff = Φcl + 1/2*(κ2 - 4*ω^2)*x^2 + 1/2*v2*z^2;

G = 1; Mcl = 2.2; a = 0.182;
κ2 = 1.8; ω = 1; v2 = 7.6;

E0 = -3.2;
```

and create the corresponding contour plot

```
rm = 1;
P0 = ContourPlot3D[Φeff == E0, {x, -rm, rm}, {y, -rm, rm}, {z, -rm, rm},
     Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Now I want the following: Define $N$ $(x,y,z)$ points, let's say $N = 10000$, equally placed on this 3D surface. In other words, I want to recreate this surface using $N$ points to cover the surface fully. Of course, the inside of this surface will be hollow again.

I am using version 9.0 of Mathematica.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by equally placed? The distance between the points have to be equal or what?

Comment: @RunnyKine I mean that there must be so many points $(N)$ so that there no holes in the outer shell. The interior should not be visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can use `DiscretizeGraphics` and `RandomPoint` to achieve what you want:

```
P0 = ContourPlot3D[Φeff == E0, {x, -rm, rm}, {y, -rm, rm}, {z, -rm, rm}, 
                   Mesh -> None, Lighting -> None];
```

Note the `Lighting -> None` option, this is to circumvent a bug in `DiscretizeGraphics` that the good people at Wolfram refuse to fix.

```
gg = DiscretizeGraphics[P0];
pts = RandomPoint[gg, 30000]; (* increase the number of points if you like *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Well, I'm using v9 and `DiscretizeGraphics` as well as `RandomPoint` are not recognized.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z. How was I supposed to know your version of *Mathematica*?

Comment: I'm really sorry. I will edit my post, including the version.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Φcl = (-G*Mcl)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + a^2];
Φeff = Φcl + 1/2*(κ2 - 4*ω^2)*x^2 + 1/2*v2*z^2;

G = 1; Mcl = 2.2; a = 0.182;
κ2 = 1.8; ω = 1; v2 = 7.6;

E0 = -3.2;

rm = 1;
P0 = ContourPlot3D[Φeff == E0, {x, -rm, rm}, {y, -rm, rm}, {z, -rm, rm},
     Mesh -> None]
```

Now extract the points from the surface

```
pts = First@Cases[P0, GraphicsComplex[points_, ___] :> points, Infinity]
Length[pts]
```

> 26684

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

You can use `Interpolation` to generate a function for the surface as well using the data as a whole or segmentwise.